# coverage layer as water network

Tags: polygon, line, network, water

I have polyline featureclass as water network. I want to create polygon layer around these line to became coverage layer but I want that to be automated and isn't manual.

Comment: What GIS software are you using?  What have you tried?

Comment: You can use the _buffer_ tool. All you need is to define the width of the river/stream). If you check the "dissolve" option, you will have one polygone for the entire network.

Comment: but h need to one polygon around all network

Comment: I am not sure I understand.

Comment: https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/editing/a-quick-tour-of-editing.htm

Comment: Perhaps try line density followed by reclassification of resulting raster .

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site.  Please check out our short [tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  Please do not keep asking the same question - we need you to edit this one.

Answer (score 2):

The *buffer* tool allows you to create a buffer zone around features. For each waterway, this is going to produce a polygon with a constant width.

[image]

Instead of "Linear Unit", you can decide to use a field to adapt the width of the buffer. The complete documentation of the tool is available [here](https://pro.arcgis.com/fr/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/analysis/buffer.htm).

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a new feature class
2. [Edit](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/editing/a-quick-tour-of-editing.htm) / draw the polygon